# If $F$ is a finite Galois extension over $K$ and $Gal(F/K)$ is abelian, then every subfield of $F$ containing $K$ is stable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am studying Galois theory and ran across this problem.

> If $F$ is a finite Galois extension over $K$ and $Gal(F/K)$ is abelian, then every subfield of $F$ containing $K$ is stable. Is the converse true?

How can I prove this? I guess the converse is false.

Comment: The fields that an intermediate field $L$ can be mapped to by elements of ${\rm Gal}(F/K)$ are the intermediate fields $K$-isomorphic to $L$, and those are the intermediate fields corresponding to conjugate subgroups of ${\rm Gal}(F/L)$ inside ${\rm Gal}(F/K)$. Therefore saying every intermediate field maps only to itself under ${\rm Gal}(F/K)$ is the same as saying all subgroups are normal.  Abelian groups are *not* the only finite groups in which all subgroups are normal. Another example is $Q_8$. More generally, look up "Dedekind groups" or "Hamiltonian groups".

Comment: @KCd Thank you for your comment. Can you also give some idea on how to prove the forward direction?

Comment: I don't know which part of the comments I made is the "forward direction".

Comment: @KCd I mean if I understood correctly your first comment proved the converse of the statement is false. I wonder if you have any tips on proving the statement itself.

Comment: An intermediate field is stable if and only if it is itself a Galois extension of $K$, and Galois theory tells us that the intermediate fields that are Galois over the base field are exactly the intermediate fields whose corresponding subgroups in ${\rm Gal}(F/K)$ are *normal* subgroups. In an abelian group, all subgroups are normal, QED.

Comment: @KCd this should be an answer, so the op can accept and you get your well deserved points...